# Docker installer wont start on Windows 10

Tags: docker

I'm trying to install Docker on Windows but I can't seem to get it work. I tried 4.0.0 - 4.13, all the same result: installer won't start, I clicked on setup, I can see "loading" cursor for 2 seconds, then it's like I didn't start anything. Installer simply terminates, not showing in process manager.
I don't even know how to start investigating, any ideas?

Comment: Are u installing docker desktop?

Comment: yea (additional characters so that I can comment)

Comment: Can you run it with an administrator privileges?

Comment: I tried, but I got the same

Comment: you can always try to setup docker in the WSL2 if docker desktop isn't working

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. I had to clean the Windows registry with "CClean" software.